# Exporting the data analytics from salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, integration

Hello is it possible to export all the SFMC analytics data to an outside BI. What I'm trying to do is have an MDM then that MDM will connect my SFMC to a BI Cognos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, very much and there are multiple ways you can extract tracking data out of SFMC -

1. Using Query Activities
   [Query Activity](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/)
2. Using Tracking Extracts
   [Tracking Extract](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/data_extract_activity/extract_types/tracking_extract/using_tracking_extracts/)
3. Using API
   [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/web_service_guide.htm)

For SMS Tracking, look at the Tracking section on the page below. Although it is not as comprehensive as Email -
[SMS Tracking](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/mobile_messages/)

From my experience, use a combination of Queries and Tracking Extracts and get the data into your MDM for analytics. Hope this helps

Comment: What about for web/mobile analytic. Example shopping cart abundant card.

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

As @ Maneesh explained those are a few of the common options. There are some caveats depending on the volume of data. Using the SOAP API there are some limits in terms of the amount of data that can be pulled, so you need to care for managing the multiple transactions needed to page and pull larger data volumes. For example, if you have thousands, or even millions, of subscribers as part of your list(s), then you will want to factor that into your approach. Also, depending the volume of campaigns and the configuration of your account, certain approaches may work better than others. For example, some people teams want to have more of a real-time transactional view by campaign. All of this then needs to align with how you pipeline data in Cognos.

We have done various integrations with SFMC to support the exact use case you are describing. If you want to discuss further, just send me a note.